Server appearing offline to browser, even though it is online
I have launched 8 or 9 webservers, personally, and something is very unusual this time regarding http/https transfer with apache2. Ports 80 and 443 are up, as indicated by nmap on a remote client machine:
nmap -Pn -p 80 xx.xx.xx.xx
Starting Nmap x.xx ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-12-05 22:31 CST
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)
Host is up (0.019s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.09 seconds

I'm listening on port 80, as confirmed by netstat on the server. If I omit
-Pn,

which according to the man page will
"Treat all hosts as online -- skip host discovery,"

I receive the following feedback:
nmap -p 80 xx.xx.xx.xx
Starting Nmap x.xx ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-12-05 22:31 CST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.16 seconds

Why does it not ping with nmap, unless I force it with the -Pn option? I haven't been able to get any browser to pull up the default apache page that is standard procedure when you first launch a webserver, either, for some reason.
I should mention, perhaps, that I had a cyber attack two weeks ago that went straight for the bios, and I have had to beef up security in a number of different ways since then. Edit: I had this particular configuration running in an identical manner though two weeks ago.

We really only handle basic webserver configuration here (such as redirects). This has been migrated to Server Fault for you, where hopefully you're receive answers from other server administrators.
